# Continue timer even back button or another activity is opened

Tags: android, timer, countdown, back-button, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a CountDownTimer App with some influence from the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). The App has a button and textview. When the button is clicked the countdown starts and when the same button is clicked the countdown timer stops. The timer is getting stopped when I press the back button or navigate to another activity in the App.

I want the timer to continue counting down even when the above operations are performed and the activity should be destroyed only when the timer isn't running.

How can I do this? Can anyone give me an in detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you navigate to next activity your current one goes to onPause()(if not finished()), and the UI thread goes to sleep, so in order to update your timer when you leave and again come back to the activity is updating the UI whenever your Activity resumes itself(which is what onResume() is for). Trying using a boolean to detect pause event this is because when the activity starts it calls onResume also.

So summary is whenever leaving current activity store a boolean and while returning check it in onResume() and update Ui accordingly. Hope this helps.